# async function vs async function inside non async function?

Tags: javascript

```
function scaryClown() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('a')
    }, 1000)
  });
}

function msg2() {
  const msg2 = async () => {
    const result = await scaryClown()
    console.log(result)
  }

  msg2()
}

async function msg() {
  const result = await scaryClown()
  console.log(result)
}
```

What is the difference between the two functions msg and msg2?

Comment: The async one returns a promise, the other not? Seems quite trivial... Please check documentation on `async` and what functions return.

Answer (score 2):

`msg` returns a promise, `msg2` (the outer one) doesn't. That means it's possible for code calling `msg` to know when the asynchronous operation completes, but it's not possible for code calling `msg2`.

*(`msg2` also fails to handle rejection or pass the chain to the caller so the caller can handle rejection, which breaks one of the fundamental rules of promises: always either handle rejection or return the chain.)*

Answer (score 1):

Let us see this step by step.
1st) Both the function will generate similar output after execution i.e.

> a

2nd) The `msg` function uses just the `await` syntax. In this, there is one function call and hence the event loop and the call stack have just one function in it. The function called `scaryClown()` is added to the call stack and then executed.

3rd) The `msg2` function has another variable i.e. `const msg2` which contains the function. Hence this approach firstly increases one extra declaration. Secondly when function `msg2` is called, it internally calls `msg2` declared inside hence increasing one more function call, adds it to the call stack. Now the event loop waits for the inner `msg2` to execute and then clears it from the stack. Then the outer `msg2` execution is completed.

For further clarity on the subject of the event loop and call stack you can refer this article - [asynchronous javascript event loop](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff)